# Why is protobuf not getting uninstalled in docker?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, pip, dockerfile, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build a python Dockerfile with some requirements as shown below:

```
botocore==1.20.112
boto3==1.17.112
numpy==1.19.1
pandas==1.1.5
protobuf==3.20.*.    # This is the version of protobuf that I want
pynamodb==5.0.3
sagemaker==2.46.0
scipy==1.6.2
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# COPY some_folder .

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

As can be seen, I am using a base image with its own requirements which are:

```
boto3==1.26.35
botocore==1.29.88
certifi==2022.12.7
chardet==4.0.0
confluent-kafka==1.7.0
dictdiffer==0.8.1
greenlet==2.0.1
idna==2.10
datadog==0.45.0
datadog-lambda==4.74.0
jmespath==1.0.1
pydantic==1.8.2
pynamodb==5.3.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-json-logger==2.0.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.25.1
s3transfer==0.6.0
sentry-sdk==1.11.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.27
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.15
websocket-client==0.57.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
pydash==7.0.1
```

When I build my Dockerfile, it is somehow installing the `protobuf-4.23.3.dist-info` package, which I checked is being installed from the base image. So now I have following in my docker container:

```
protobuf-3.20.3.dist-info
protobuf-3.20.3-py3.8-nspkg.pth
protobuf3_to_dict-0.1.5-py3.8.egg-info
protobuf-4.23.3.dist-info
```

I tried adding `RUN pip3 uninstall protobuf` before installing my requirements in Dockerfile, but still the `protobuf-4.23.3.dist-info` is not getting uninstalled.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I tried adding `RUN pip3 uninstall protobuf` before installing my requirements in Dockerfile, but still the `protobuf-4.23.3.dist-info` is not getting uninstalled.

How can I just install the `protobuf==3.20.*` version for my docker?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think you cannot use multiple versions of the same package in one Python process. The container likely includes the `protobuf` version because one of its components takes a dependency on that version. If you uninstall it, you'll risk breaking something else. Ideally, you'd unify your solution on a single (most recent) version of the dependencies (including `protobuf`). Another solution is to use a less opinionated base image e.g. [`python`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) and `pip install` your requirements but then you'll lose access to the components from the other base image.